# NodeJS why i can't use nonrelative imports (error TS2307: Cannot find module)

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm using the express framework in NodeJS with typescript in the backend. Unfortunately, I get a very annoying error:

> error TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/interfaces/vault' or its
> corresponding type declarations.

Here are some details about my app:

**folder structure (shortened)**

```
.
├── node_modules
├── src
│   ├── controllers
│   │   └── test.ts
│   ├── interfaces
│   │   └── vault.ts
│   └── index.ts
└── tsconfig.json
└── tslint.json
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "*": [
                "node_modules/*"
            ]
        }
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

The error appears, when I import an interface, class, or something else from another file, by a nonrelative path. Here is an example, in which the test controller, tries to import the vault interface.

```
// not working
import { iVault } from "src/interfaces/vault";

// working
import { iVault } from "../interfaces/vault";
```

I know there are a lot of similar questions out there. But no provided solutions helped me.
From my understanding, the nonrelative import should work because of the include section of my tsconfig.json. I also use node as moduleResolution. So I really can't find the mistake.